Find an example such that $\int_{E}f\neq\sum_{j}\inf[\sup_{x\in E_{j}}f(x)]|E_{j}|$
The question is exercise 5.25 of An Introduction to Real Analysis by Wheeden and Zygmund:

Let $f$ be nonnegative and measurable on $E$. Give an example to show that $$\int_{E}f=\inf\sum_{j}\left[\sup_{x\in E_{j}}f(x)\right]|E_{j}|$$ is false, where the infimum is taken over all decompositions $E=\bigcup_{j}E_{j}$ of $E$ into the union of finite disjoint measurable sets $E_{j}$.

Inspired by the proof of theorem 5.8 in the same book (same statement but interchanging the $sup$ and $inf$), I tried to construct $g_{k}=\sum_{j}[\sup_{x\in E_{j}^{k}} f(x)]\chi_{E_{j}^{k}}=\chi_{[k,+\infty)}$ because it's the counterexample of $\int g_{k}\nrightarrow\int g$ that I knew. I also tried the Cantor-Lebesgue function but it didn't work (I'm not sure about this). I hope for any advice or hints, thanks!
Edit: If $f$ is a simple function, the equality holds. Thus the characteristic function on some weird measurable set is not the counterexample, and that's the reason I tried the Lebesgue function.
